# Xamarin Forms - center title in a stacklayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The screenshot below shows a header that includes a hamburger menu and a title.  Notice how the title is centered on it's bounding area (the red box).  How can I get the title to center on the width of the phone, but leave the hamburger menu where it is?

Here is the code that creates the header area...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WP.MobileMidstream.Device.Pages.RunSheetHeader">
    <ContentView.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="StackLayout">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#00458C" />
        </Style>
    </ContentView.Resources>
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}">
            <StackLayout.HeightRequest>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                    <On Platform="iOS">80</On>
                    <On Platform="Android">56</On>
                </OnPlatform>
            </StackLayout.HeightRequest>
            <Image Source="hamburger_icon" 
                   Margin="10" />
            <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   FontSize="20"
                   BackgroundColor="Red"
                   TextColor="White">Daily Run Sheet</Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

[image]

Comment: I would use a Grid (1 row x 2 cols) instead.  Have the Label extend across both cols, then place the hamburger icon in just the first cell, AFTER the label

Comment: I agree with @Jason you should use a grid for this application. In general you should try and avoid `StackLayout` because it is very expensive to put onscreen. Grid is a much more useful tool for xamarin forms ui!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jason suggested a Grid instead of the StackLayout.  Here is what I came up with that works.  Thanks @Jason!

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WP.MobileMidstream.Device.Pages.RunSheetHeader">
    <ContentView.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#00458C" />
        </Style>
    </ContentView.Resources>
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition.Height>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="GridLength">
                            <On Platform="iOS">80</On>
                            <On Platform="Android">56</On>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </RowDefinition.Height>
                </RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                   FontSize="20"
                   TextColor="White">Daily Run Sheet</Label>
            <Image Source="hamburger_icon" 
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Margin="10" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```