# Xamarin, xaml titleview with centered title with buttons

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a TitleView where the navigation title is centered in the middle of the screen. But have buttons on either or both sides.

(I recently found posts saying it was best to add buttons to the TitleView rather than ContentPage.ToolbarItem as we couldn't changes the colour of the text.)

Instead we opted for fixed width buttons / spacers, so we could have a middle label for the title which would be centered. You can see the result below, unforunetly I'm going to have to increased the size of the button for longer text. We also support several languages so the text could be longer still.

[image]

Here's the xaml

```
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource TitleViewStackLayout}">
            <Label Style="{StaticResource TitleViewSpacer}"
                   HorizontalOptions="Start" />
            <Label Text="{tran:Translate Contact_ConfirmEmail}"
                   Style="{StaticResource TitleViewLabel}" />
            <Button Style="{StaticResource TitleViewButton}"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    Text="{tran:Translate Common_Restart}"
                    Command="{Binding ToolbarItemRestartCommand}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

And here's our style...

```
            <Style x:Key="TitleViewStackLayout" TargetType="StackLayout">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource DarkBlue}" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />

                <Setter Property="Spacing" Value="0" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="TitleViewLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource White}" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource Title}" />
            </Style>
            <OnPlatform x:Key="TitleViewItemMargin" x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Android="10,0,10,0" iOS="0" />
            <OnPlatform x:Key="TitleViewItemWidth" x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Android="60" iOS="50" />
            <Style x:Key="TitleViewButton" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource DarkBlue}" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource White}" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{DynamicResource TitleViewItemMargin}" />
                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="{DynamicResource TitleViewItemWidth}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="TitleViewSpacer" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource DarkBlue}" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource White}" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{DynamicResource TitleViewItemMargin}" />
                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="{DynamicResource TitleViewItemWidth}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            </Style>
```

I did think about using a grid, I know could also add three columns all with Grid.Column="0".. but I'd then have the possibility of a long title which would overlap the buttons. We do have some long titles. I guess I would need to be able to set a max width and add `LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"`

[Xamarin Forms - center title in a stacklayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062421/xamarin-forms-center-title-in-a-stacklayout)

I did think about repeating the text but transparent to achieve equal widths, but this wouldn't cater for 2 different buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said , it could be  better to use **Grid** instead of **StackLayout** .

In your case , you could set the width of three columns as a fixed percentage value. In this way , since the Text of Label is a long value , it will never cover the right Button .

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <Grid >

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.6*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0"
               Text="Back"
               MaxLines="1"
               Style="{StaticResource TitleViewSpacer}"
               HorizontalOptions="Start" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Email Confirm Email Confirm Email Confirm Email Confirm Email Confirm"
               MaxLines="1"
               LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"  // you could set it or not , both are OK ,it's up to you
               Style="{StaticResource TitleViewLabel}" />
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource TitleViewButton}"
                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                Text="Restart"
                WidthRequest="80"
                Command="{Binding ToolbarItemRestartCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Comment: Thanks will this crop / trim the `button` text if it is longer ?

Comment: Yes , it will like Re..rt .

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go, is it ok if take a few days to get back to this task before accepting?

Comment: If have any other issue you could update the question and @me .

Comment: At'ing doesn't work, I assumed you had that turned off

Comment: For your column definitions use `ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto, *"`. This way your title will only take up the space it needs in the center and the other buttons have full access to the width of the title view